# Check if Text Data is in Date Format

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem in my SQL.
 I have a table named tblseaexport with columns, ShipmentID, Remarks. Remarks columns is set with a TEXT property. If I have a sample data:

```
 ShipmentID    Remarks
 S000123       Advised Shipper
 S000124       2014-01-24
 S000125       2014-01-25
```

How can I select all rows where Remarks' value is in date format in SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YOu can use something like:

```
select t.*
from t
where Remarks regexp '^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$'
```

Comment: How can I check now if Remarks is not in DateForm. I should display now the records which remarks <> DateFormat

Comment: @user3172200 . . . You can use either `where not (Remarks regexp '^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$')` or `where Remarks not regexp '^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$'.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
select date_format(Date(Remarks),'%Y-%m-%d') from table1
where STR_TO_DATE(Remarks,'%Y-%m-%d') IS NOT NULL
```